# Running Rego Tests in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, open-policy-agent, rego

I am trying to run rego test cases as part of jenkins pipeline run. I previously had my test case and the input data for the test case in a single file and they all ran successfully.

I modified my test cases to read the data from an external json file and the current folder structure is as follows: test.rego file and input.json file in same folder.

This is what I use in Jenkins to run the tests `*./opa test -b -v .*`

The tests are failing with the error `data.utilities.test_no_OwnerContact: FAIL`
I am assuming this is because the rego test is unable to read the data from input.json

When I am trying to pass the input file explicitly using `-i/--input`, I see an error in jenkins as `Error: unknown flag: --input`

I am not sure if I am using the required tags or if it is something else.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Edit: I printed the files in the bundle, and I see the data.json file present. So the OPA engine is not able to read the data file from the Bundle. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you'd specify input data in tests is not with an input.json file, but by mocking the input using the `with` .. `as` construct. An example test mocking input might look something like this:

```
test_with_mocked_input {
    allow with input as {
        "deployment_name": "testing",
        "replicas": 2 
    }
}
```

See the docs on [data mocking](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-testing/#data-mocking) for further info.